# Javascript split text & then loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some text "lorem ipsum^^^text^^^testtext" that I want to split onto new lines. I'm using split to separate the text into an array like so:

```
var companySplit = this.company.split('^^^');
```

and I can output this like so:

```
$("#company").html(companySplit[0] + '<br />' + companySplit[1]);
```

However, In certain situations, there may not be 2 array items...There could be 3 or 4 for example. How can I display the array items separated by a line break regardless of the amount of items? I've tried using a loop but I'm unfamiliar with them so I had trouble getting it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do a loop, you would basically write:

```
for(var i = 0, l = companySplit.length; i < l; i++) {
   $('#company')
       .append('<br/>')
       .append(companySplit[i]);
}
```

You may want to check the value of `i` to avoid inserting a break before the first item.

```
if(i > 0)
   $('#company').append('<br/>');
$('#company').append(companySplit[i]);
```

But in your case a simple join would be enough:

```
$('#company').html(companySplit.join('<br/>'));
```

Or, for that matter, a replace:

```
$('#company').html(this.company.replace(/\^\^\^/g, '<br/>'));
```

Comment: the replace solution is perfect for what I'm trying to achieve. Much simpler, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a for() loop.

```
var result[] = this.company.split('^^^');
var out;
for(int i=0,j=result.length; i<j; j++) {
  out += result[i] + '<br />';}
$("#company").html(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 var companySplit = this.company.split('^^^');
 var htmlContent="";
   for(int count=0;count<companySplit.length;count++)
   {
      htmlContent=htmlContent+companySplit[count] + '<br />'

   }
   $("#company").html(htmlContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var i=0;
$.each(companySplit,function(){

$("#company").html(companySplit[i] + '<br />' + companySplit[i+1]);
i++;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(company.split('^^^'), function(index, value) { 
  $("#company").append(value+'<br/>');
});​
```